# Ломается eventListener

Tags: javascript, анимация

Есть 12 блоков. Выполняется css анимация при помощи добавления в блок определенного класса через js. нужно, чтоб каждый блок выполнял анимацию поочередно, а так же анимация происходила при скроле. проблема в том, что, когда видимые блоки в окне браузера выполнили свою анимацию, потом начинаешь скролить - ничего не происходит. А когда скролишь при незавершенной анимации - все прекрасно работает. проблема в **функции animOnScroll()** не срабатывает **addEventListener** *в конце функции* в местах:

```
if (i < animItems.length) {
                animOnScroll();
            } else {
                window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
            }
```

Вот код js:

```
const animItems = document.getElementsByClassName("animItems");
let i = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
function animOnScroll() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
    const animItem = animItems[i];
    i++;
    const animItemHeight = animItem.offsetHeight;
    const animItemOffset = offset(animItem).top;

    let animItemPoint = window.innerHeight;

    if ((pageYOffset > animItemOffset - animItemPoint) && pageYOffset < (animItemOffset + animItemHeight)) {
        animItem.classList.add('_active');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
        animItem.ontransitionend = function() {
            if (i < animItems.length) {
                animOnScroll();
            } else {
                window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
            }
        };
    } else {
        if (i < animItems.length) {
            animOnScroll();
        } else {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
        }
    }
}
function offset(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}
setTimeout(animOnScroll, 100);
```

вот css, если нужен:

```
.box {
    width: 1100px;
}
.animItems {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #555;
    margin: 20px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
._active {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

и html:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
    <div class="animItems"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Разобрался

Оказывается, проблемы была не в eventListener, как думал я, а в том, что счетчик i после первого прохода равнялся 12 и при вторичном прогоне по циклу он начинал с числа 13, а как вы помните, блоков всего 12 и поэтому он не мог найти 13 блок по счету.

---

Было решено в конце цикла добавить присваивание счетчику номер последнего элемента, которому был добавлен класс *_active*. Выглядит вот так: `i = document.getElementsByClassName('_active').length;` и поместил это в те самые элементы с условием в конце:

```
if (i < animItems.length) {
                animOnScroll();
            } else {
                //вот здесь
                i = document.getElementsByClassName('_active').length;

                window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
            }
```

если кому интересно, вот полный js, который у меня получился:

```
const animItems = document.getElementsByClassName("animItems");
let i = 0;
function animOnScroll() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
    const animItem = animItems[i];
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    let animItemHeight = animItem.offsetHeight;
    const animItemOffset = offset(animItem).top;

    let animItemPoint = window.innerHeight;

    if ((pageYOffset > animItemOffset - animItemPoint) && pageYOffset < (animItemOffset + animItemHeight)) {
        animItem.classList.add('_active');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
        animItem.ontransitionend = function() {
            if (i < animItems.length) {
                animOnScroll();
            } else {
                i = document.getElementsByClassName('_active').length;
                window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
            }
        };
    } else {
        if (i < animItems.length) {
            animOnScroll();
        } else {
            i = document.getElementsByClassName('_active').length;
            window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
        }
    }
}
function offset(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}
setTimeout(animOnScroll, 100);
```